# Bootstrap modal stopping checkbox from selecting

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I have a checkbox on the bottom of my page. When the user clicks it, I want a popup to show up. Everything works except the toggling of the checkbox. When I click the checkbox using the code below the pop up appears but the box does not check. Any idea why?

The jQuery:

```
$('#confirm-final').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $(this).find('.danger').attr('href', $(e.relatedTarget).data('href'));
});
```

The checkbox:

```
<label class="checkbox-inline"><asp:CheckBox ID="chkFinalSubmission" runat="server" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-final"/>Final Submission</label>
```

The popup:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="confirm-final" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            Final Submission
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            If you check final submission and submit this ad note, <strong>you will not be able to change it anymore.</strong> It will be permanently stuck in readonly mode.
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <asp:Button ID="btnConfirmFinal" runat="server" Text="Got it" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, then, If I do not have the full page, I can not help more. The full trick is on how its rendered, and what bootstrap expect to get as render.

Comment: Here's the full page if you want to take a look: http://pastebin.com/cqDhWEgm

Answer (score 1):

As for the why, the event that is fired to open a modal contains `e.preventDefault()`, which cancels any event that might have occurred by clicking the modal-invoking element. If it's a link, the href doesn't get followed but the modal opens instead. If it's a checkbox, the actual check is cancelled. This is built-in behavior, and you can't prevent it.

How to solve it:

In Bootstrap 3 you have access to the `relatedTarget` property of the event that fired the modal.  Since your function already uses `relatedTarget` I'm assuming you use Bootstrap 3 indeed. You could just add the following rule to your existing jquery function:

```
$(e.relatedTarget).prop('checked', !$(e.relatedTarget).prop('checked'));
```

(This sets the checkbox to the inverse of the already existing 'checked' state, aka it toggles it on and off everytime you click).

Also, are you sure the rest of your code works? You refer to `$(e.relatedTarget).data('href')` but your checkbox has no `data-href`. Did you mean `data('target')` instead?

Comment: Thank you for the reply and explanation. Web programming is new to me so that was a huge help! And yes - I did mean `data('target')` ... unfortunately, it still doesn't work. It shows the modal and the check box remains - the same - unchecked.

Comment: Have you looked in your console yet to see if you get error messages? Open up the browser's dev tools (usually F11, or cmd-alt-i on mac) and click the console tab. Maybe that will tell you something. If it doesn't say anything, replace my line with: `console.log(e.relatedTarget)` and post what it says then when you open the modal)

Comment: Hmm, it looks like I was mistaken and Bootstrap 3 should in fact not cancel the check, that's only in Bootstrap 2.3. Which version are you even using? Maybe there's another reason your checkbox doesn't work.

Comment: I am using 3.0. I don't see anything in the console when I click the checkbox... so I guess it's never being called

Comment: Are you able to show an actual working example where this occurs, on your site or reproduced on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I've never used jsfiddle before. I was able to get this: http://jsfiddle.net/gsf9o1jp/ - what's weird about this is the alert I have setup in the jsfiddle works on their page but not on mine. I do not receive any alerts when I run it on my machine.

Comment: In this fiddle you put `asp:Button` elements, but it's not an ASP environment so it didn't turn into a checkbox, the browser just renders it as a normal element. This is going to be really hard to debug without the actal HTML that's being output

Comment: Sorry for being a pain. I just did this one: http://jsfiddle.net/swgqaze6/ and it does exactly what's happening on my page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61638/discussion-between-stephan-muller-and-duckwizzle).